# Why arr.flat.base is different from the a.ravel().base?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to dig a bit into how Numpy works internally, and I am confused about some stuff regarding the `base` and the array flattening.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12, dtype=int).reshape((3, 4))
```

So, we have this easy array. Then I try to use `flat` and `ravel()`:

```
flat_iter = a.flat
print(flat_iter.base is a)
```

This prints me `True`, which is kind of what I was expecting.

```
a_ravel = a.ravel()
print(a_ravel.base is a)
```

However, this gives me `False`. Why?

The `flat_iter.base` seems to correspond to the reshaped `a` array, i.e. `np.arange(12, dtype=int).reshape((3, 4))`. However, `a_ravel.base` seems to correspond to `np.arange(12, dtype=int)`.

I've tried to google about it, but I did not really understand why this happens. Why would the `base` behavior be different between two?

Comment: The `arange` makes an array.  `a` is a view of that.  `ravel` is another view (just another `reshape`)  I like to check `.__array_interface__` rather than `base`

Comment: @hpaulj but why then `a.flat.base` considers `a` its base, not `arange` (like in the case with `ravel`)?

Comment: I know `flatten` makes a copy, but haven't pais much attention to `flat`..I've only used it for assignment purposes.

Comment: @hpaulj same, I haven't used `flat` before. The difference between `ravel` and `flatten` is pretty clear (one returns a copy, one tries not to copy). `flat` is supposed to be just an iterator for the flattened array. But why would its `base` behave differently - I am really clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [82]: a = np.arange(5)
In [83]: b = a.reshape(5,1)
In [84]: c = b.ravel()
In [85]: biter=b.flat
```

Now check the databuffer location:

```
In [86]: a.__array_interface__['data']
Out[86]: (44761168, False)
In [87]: b.__array_interface__['data']
Out[87]: (44761168, False)
In [88]: c.__array_interface__['data']
Out[88]: (44761168, False)
```

All the same, `b` and `c` are views.  But:

```
In [89]: biter.__array_interface__['data']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-89-9d5e2ed1a08d>", line 1, in <module>
    biter.__array_interface__['data']
AttributeError: 'numpy.flatiter' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

`flatiter` is not an array!

```
In [90]: a.base              # None
In [91]: b.base
Out[91]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [92]: b.base is a
Out[92]: True
In [93]: c.base is a
Out[93]: True
```

As expected for views, the `b` and `c` base are both `a`.

But the `b.flat` base is `b`:

```
In [94]: biter.base
Out[94]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
In [95]: biter.base is b
Out[95]: True
In [96]: biter.base is a      # not a
Out[96]: False
```

Again `biter` is not an array, so doesn't 'obey' the same `base` logic.

Regardless of the `base`, modifying the `biter` modifies `b` and `a` (and `c`):

```
In [97]: biter[::2] = 10
In [98]: b
Out[98]: 
array([[10],
       [ 1],
       [10],
       [ 3],
       [10]])
In [99]: a
Out[99]: array([10,  1, 10,  3, 10])
```

So the short answer is that a `flatiter` base is not the same thing as a `view's` base`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! An example I was reading used those two `base` in the same context as if they were suppose to mean the same thing, so it got me confused.